# Setting focal_length fails in set_proj_type method in Matplotlib 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection

I am animating some data using mpl_toolkits.mplot3d. When I attempt to set the focal length in the set_proj_type method, it fails.

When I use the following, the code runs with a default focal length of 1.

`ax.set_proj_type('persp')`

But when I attempt to change the focal length as follows, it fails to run

`ax.set_proj_type('persp', focal_length = 0.2)`

and gives me this error:

`TypeError: set_proj_type() got an unexpected keyword argument 'focal_length'`

But this is exactly how the focal length is shown to be specified in the [Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/projections.html).

I am running Python 3.8.10 on Linux and Matplotlib version 3.1.2 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I've found how to install the latest stable release 3.6.3 (why I was not getting it through the package manager I do not know).

Apparently the focal_length attribute was not available in Matplotlib version 3.1.2. Updating to the new release makes it available.

But now the camera distance attribute has been deprecated for 3D plots, which breaks something that was working for me. I'll post that in a separate question.